# Firebase email verify email issue

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6, angularfire

Using Angular v6 with AngularFire2.

Having trouble with redirects using firebase emails for verify and reset password.

**My code that works:**

```
  public verifyEmail(email: string): Observable<any> {
    const verify = this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification();
    return from(verify.then(response => response).catch(e => e));
  }
```

The above code sends an email.

The user clicks the link in the email and then it redirects it to my website e.g. dashboard.

I added a **custom url** to the firebase template but only allows one for all email templates.

But I need different redirect urls for **reset and verify emails.**

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you please help us understand the use case here? Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: I have my own reset password page that I need the email to redirect too and my own verified email confirmation page

Comment: Did you try [Customizing the action link URL](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714#actionlink)?

Comment: yeh I changed the customize action URL to myurl/reset-password and to myurl/verified-email. But will only let me have one for all the email templates. very strange